# Find the total of the same column from multiple sheets and express totals next to sheet name on new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a macro that will display the Sum from a set column of each of multiple sheets. I need the total of column "K" to be shown 1 row from the last entry of a variable number of entries. It is a requirment that this is in VBA as it needs to run with a number of other functions.

I've tried the below code but it does not give the expected result and seems to be drawing data from other sheets.

```
Sub SumWorksheets()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets

        LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("K" & LastRow + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("K2:K" & ws.Rows.Count))

    Next

End Sub
```

I want the Total of all numbers in Column "K" to display 2 rows below the last number in Row "K"

Comment: maybe you need to change the code for the LastRow to get the last row from Column K instead of Column A. "LastRow = ws.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row"

Answer (score 0):

Declared and fully use `ws` and `LastRow` variables. Not using can cause code to pull values from another worksheet. Per comment from @LoveCoding, using a different column as the `LastRow` can overwrite a cell in `Col K`. You should have used the `LastRow` variable, in the Sum function.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    LastRow = ws.Range("K" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("K" & LastRow + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("K2:K" & LastRow))
Next
```